# T-SQL query to remove duplicates from large tables using join

Tags: t-sql, join, sql-delete

I am new in using T-SQL queries and I was trying different solutions in order to remove duplicate rows from a fairy large table (with over 270,000 rows). 
The table looks something like:

```
TableA
-----------
RowID int not null identity(1,1) primary key,
Col1 varchar(50) not null,
Col2 int not null,
Col3 varchar(50) not null
```

The rows for this table are not perfect duplicates because of the existence of the RowID identity field. 
The second table that I need to join with:

```
TableB
-----------
RowID int not null identity(1,1) primary key,
Col1 int not null,
Col2 varchar(50) not null
```

In TableA I have something like:

```
1 | gray | 4     | Angela 
2 | red  | 6     | Diana
3 | black| 6     | Alina
4 | black| 11    | Dana
5 | gray | 4     | Angela 
6 | red  | 12    | Dana
7 | red  | 6     | Diana
8 | black| 11    | Dana
```

And in TableB:

```
1 | 6  | klm
2 | 11 | lmi
```

Second column from TableB (Col1) is foreign key inside TableA (Col2).
I need to remove ONLY the duplicates from TableA that has Col2 = 6 ignoring the other duplicates.

```
    1 | gray | 4     | Angela 
    2 | red  | 6     | Diana
    4 | black| 6     | Alina
    5 | black| 11    | Dana
    6 | gray | 4     | Angela 
    7 | red  | 12    | Dana
    8 | black| 11    | Dana
```

I tried using

```
DELETE FROM TableA a inner join TableB b on a.Col2=b.Col1
WHERE a.RowId NOT IN (SELECT MIN(RowId) FROM TableA GROUP BY RowId, Col1, Col2, Col3) and b.Col2="klm"
```

but I still get some of the duplicates that I need to remove.

What is the best way to remove not perfect duplicate rows using join?

Answer (score 0):

well min would only be one and group by PK will give you everything
and the RowID are wrong in the example

```
DELETE FROM TableA a 
inner join TableB b 
       on a.Col2=b.Col1
WHERE a.RowId NOT IN (SELECT MIN(RowId) 
                      FROM TableA GROUP BY RowId, Col1, Col2,   Col3) 
and b.Col2="klm"
```

this would be rows to delete

```
select * 
from 
(  select *
        , row_number over (partition by Col1, Col3 order by RowID) as rn
   from TableA a
   where del.Col2 = 6
)  tt 
where tt.rn > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

another solution is:

```
WITH CTE AS(
               SELECT  t.[col1], t.[col2], t.[col3], t.[col4],
                   RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.[col1], t.[col2], t.[col3], t.[col4] ORDER BY t.[col1])
               FROM  [TableA] t
            )
            delete from  CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

regards.